# SIM800L check if call was answered

Tags: at-command, sim800, sim800l

I need to disable the dialing tone on my SIM800L and for that I need to know if the receiving end has answered the call. AT+CPAS returns 4 which stands for 'in progress' both during conversation as well as during the tone before the call is answered so it's of no use.

Is there a way using AT commands? Or should I resort to doing some singal analisis of the output audio? Is there any other device that does have this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `+CLCC`. It is a standard ETSII command, so you will find it in every cellular modem. For the present answer I will refer to the [SIM800 AT command guide](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf).

Execution command `AT+CLCC` list the status of the current calls. For each call you will get a row such as

```
+CLCC: <id1>,<dir>,<stat>,<mode>,<mpty>[,<number>,<type>,<alphaID>
```

where:

| Parameter | Description | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **`<idx>`** | Call identification number | [1-7] |
| **`<dir>`** | Direction | **0** Mobile originated (MO) call **1** Mobile terminated (MT) call |
| **`<stat>`** | State of the call | **0** Active **1** Held **2** Dialing (MO call) **3** Alerting (MO call) **4** Incoming (MT call) **5** Waiting (MT call) **6** Disconnect |
| **`<mode>`** | Bearer/tele service | **0** Voice **1** Data **2** Fax |
| **`<mpty>`** | Multiparty status | **0** Call is not one of multiparty (conference) call parties **1** Call is one of multiparty (conference) call parties |
| **`<number>`** | Remote peer phone number (String to be included in quotation marks; phone number in format specified by `<type>`) |  |
| **`<type>`** | Type of address |  |
| **`<alphaId>`** | Alphanumeric representation of `<number>` corresponding to the entry found in phone book (String type to be included in quotation marks) |  |

Usually there is only one call, but anyway you'll be able to determine the call of your interest by checking the `number` field of the answer.

---

The **`<stat>`** field of the response provides what you need. In fact, it will contain the status of the current call showing a different value between when the modem is dialing (`2`, in case of Mobile Originated call) and when the call is active (`0`; also `1` if you want to include held calls).

Comment: You just made my day!! That was it. I was already assuming I had to go rouge. Thank you!!